# Adding assemblies to the GAC from Inno Setup

Tags: .net, installation, gac, inno-setup

Until recently we were using Inno Setup for our installations, something I would like to continue doing, unless we can get an [uninstall option in the start menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61691/how-to-add-uninstall-option-in-net-setup-project) (thanks Giovanni Galbo), however we now need to GAC some external libraries, something I suspect is only doable (or at least only supported) though the .NET Setup Project.

Is it possible to call a GAC'ing library from another setup application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://jrsoftware.org/files/is5-whatsnew.htm you should be able to do it with v5.3 and above

> Added .NET support (these cause an
>   internal error if used on a system
>   with no .NET Framework present):
>
> ```
> * Added new [Files] section flag: gacinstall.
> * Added new [Files] section parameter: StrongAssemblyName.
> * Added new constants: {regasmexe}, {regasmexe32}, {regasmexe64}.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about library, but you can call [gacutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28VS.80%29.aspx) to install/uninstall assemblies.

Comment: Not a good idea.  gacutil.exe is part of the SDK and is not on a normal "Non-Devloper" machine.

Comment: Per Microsoft's documentation, you shouldn't use gacutil in production:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79(v=vs.110).aspx