# How do I add a .NET assembly to the GAC in InnoSetup?

Tags: .net, installation, gac

I'm making an installer with InnoSetup for a .NET application, and I want to register some assemblies during the install. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean register the assemblies in the GAC?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699/adding-assemblies-to-the-gac-from-inno-setup

Comment: Or do you want to register for COM interop?

Comment: Yes, I mean register the assemblies in the GAC. Not the old COM stuff, the new .NET stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try the **gacinstall** file flag? It's explained in their documentation in "Setup Script Sections" -> "[Files] section":
http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/

Comment: For more details: Source: "C:\SourceFolder\myassembly.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; StrongAssemblyName: "myassembly, Version=1.3.7.7333, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1111ec4a3c56d0bf, ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL"; Flags: ignoreversion gacinstall uninsnosharedfileprompt