# How can a setup program check whether an assembly is installed in the GAC, and if so, its version?

Tags: .net, windows, inno-setup, gac

Title says it all... Preferably for Inno Setup. I found a couple of ways, but none seem particularly convenient.

1. Using the directory structure of the GAC to check the DLL directly. This is not an official way and discouraged for various/obvious reasons.
2. Using the `gacutil` program. Not part of the framework, only the SDK, and not likely accepted for redistribution.
3. Using the [`Fusion API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404523.aspx) similar to gacutil. Requires COM interaction, but appears to be the officially favored way of doing what I'm after.

**Edit**
Just a clarification: I want to check for the existence/version of a possibly already installed GAC assembly so I can determine whether all the requirements of my application are installed (or whether I need to run a separate installation that would install these assemblies).

Comment: InnoSetup supports COM usage. Do you prefer the third option ?

Comment: I suppose it is the preferred option. Do you have some examples on how Inno interacts with COM?

Comment: Look for instance at the examples shipped with InnoSetup, specifically `CodeAutomation.iss` and `CodeAutomation2.iss`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding assemblies to the GAC from Inno Setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699/adding-assemblies-to-the-gac-from-inno-setup)

Comment: @HansPassant They don't seem to be a duplicate. That question is asking how to install it (for which there is a built in method in Inno)

Comment: @Ioan: Did you ever solved this problem? I need exactly the same as you for Inno Setup! Therefore any news on that would be great. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @ab-tools, I ended up just installing the needed assemblies without doing anything more complicated. But you could look into the third option using COM and post an answer if you have the time to figure it out.

Comment: @loan: First thanks a lot for your quick reply. I'm not so good with COM, especially not together with Pascal. ;-) I'm currently using the first option which I consider "not good", but I currently don't have any better idea and it seems to work fine for now. I just found this Pascal script probably implementing a part of the needed task already, but I currently don't have time to work into that (especially as I don't have much clue about Pascal): https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/LibFusion.pas